# Perl regex - extract two sections per line

Tags: regex, perl, shell

I am trying to extract information from log files using Perl and regex from command line:

```
cat file_1 | perl -ne 'print if s/(2015-09-..) .*for (.\d+,\d)/\1/'
2015-09-02 20:03:05,037 INFO  [ajp-bio-10.247.96.38-27032-exec-92] (RegisterOnlineAction:474) - REGISTRATION for [735078385,1]: Perform Action.
2015-09-02 20:26:41,383 INFO  [ajp-bio-10.247.96.39-27002-exec-66] (RegisterOnlineAction:474) - REGISTRATION for [724314312,1]: Perform Action.
2015-09-02 21:09:47,890 INFO  [ajp-bio-10.247.96.38-27002-exec-65] (RegisterOnlineAction:474) - REGISTRATION for [328057138,1]: Perform Bill.
```

But I do not get output I need.

What I need would be:

```
2015-09-02 735078385,1
2015-09-02 724314312,1
2015-09-02 328057138,1
```

'print if s/text/text/' makes search and replace and probably is not best way. But is there any way to select multiple sections per line and get them in output.

Comment: Update your regex to `\[(.\d+,\d)\]` to match square brackets.

Comment: this give me similar output as initial command:

cat file_1 | perl -ne 'print if s/(2015-09-..) .*for \[(.\d+,\d)\]/\1/'

2015-09-02: Perform Action.
2015-09-02: Perform Action.
2015-09-02: Perform Bill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match the square brackets, too:

```
 < file_1 perl -ne '/(2015-09-..).*for (\[[0-9,]+\])/ and print "$1 $2\n"'
```

Comment: This is it, than you very much

Answer (score 1):

you can use oneliner like this and run it from command line:

```
perl -lnae '$F[8] =~ /(\d+,\d+)/ and print join " ", $F[0], $1' file.log
```

1) key `-n` makes the loop over all lines in input file (file.log).

2) then key `-a` splits each line by whitespaces and puts nonempty values into `@F` array. so dates will be in `$F[0]` and values like "[735078385,1]:" will be in `$F[8]`. i use regexp `/(\d+,\d+)/` to extract right values from `$F[8]` (without square brackets and colon) and save it into `$1` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my version in shell using **egrep**, **awk** & **tr**

```
egrep '(2015-09-..) .*for (.[0-9]+,[0-9])' /tmp/xx | awk '{print $1,$9}' | tr -s '[]:' ' '
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just splitting and transforming?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 
use strict;
use warnings; 

while ( <> ) {
    my @stuff = split /,/;
    $stuff[2] =~ s/\].*//;
    print "$stuff[0],$stuff[2]";
}
```

Or if you're after a single line:

```
perl -ne 'print join ( ",", (map { s/\].*//g; $_ } split /,/)[0,2] );'
```